# How to automate basic sanity on android?

Tags: android, automation, adb

My aim is to run an automated test to check the bare minimum on my android build once its loaded on the device

1. Boot to the Homescreen
2. Turn WIFI on/off
3. Turn BT on/off
4. Start Camera - take snapshot
5. Switch to Camcorder - take a short video
6. Run audio and video
7. Log to a file what passed and what failed.

I would like to do this entirely using adb.exe on windows host.

What I want to know is how do I test each of the above options from adb shell command line?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Android Compatibility Test Suite (CTS)](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html).

For example, after you've downloaded the CTS test package, to test the Camera you could issue a command on the host that looks like the following:

```
./cts-tradefed run cts --class android.hardware.cts.CameraTest
```